# make paging in listview windows 8

Tags: javascript, paging, windows-8

I want to make a WinJS.UI.ListView paging, paging is working at the time I reached the last scroll index. when the index reached last, I am requesting more data to the server with the API. is this possible?

Comment: Hi Pensilhijau,
I had implemened the custom data source for listview control.I am able to show data on the first page.But when I scroll listview control upto the last item it does not load more pages.I dont know where am i going wrong.Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look at creating your own custom data source to handle this. See the MSDN article How to create a custom data source:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770849

and the accompanying sample code:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-custom-data-4dcfb128

In short, you'll be creating a class that implements the IListDataAdapter interface and using it with your own derivation of the VirtualizedDataSource class. The ListView will take care of the visual display and will call your code when it needs more data.

Comment: hi jordan, thanks.. this information very helpful, looks like i have create my own custom data source

Comment: Hi Jordan, I had implemened the custom data source for listview control.I am able to show data on the first page.But when I scroll listview control upto the last item it does not load more pages.I dont know where am i going wrong.Can you help me?

Comment: @Android_Crazy - Did you set any data-win-options for your ListView? Here's an example I've used to setup a ListView to incrementally load data: <div class="resultslist" aria-label="Search results" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{loadingBehavior:'incremental', pagesToLoadThreshold: 1}"></div>

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211835.aspx

ListView.loadingBehavior property

"incremental"
The ListView loads as many pages of items as specified by the pagesToLoad property. When automaticallyLoadItems is true, the items are loaded when the user is within the threshold scrolling amount (specified by pagesToLoadThreshold) of the end of the loaded portion of the list. When automaticallyLoadItems is false, you can manually load pages by calling the loadNextPages method. Note that, when using this mode, the ensureVisible method won't work for items that haven't loaded yet.

Comment: hi mike, thanks for your response.. do you have tutorial that use ListView.loadingBehavior?